# I want to remove the divider under the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What I'm trying to do is exactly as shown in the image"
[image: my problem]

I want to remove this divider. I'm using the android built-in action bar. I don't want to use Sherlock Action Bar. I have to use android action bar.

I have tried to add this to my styles but its not working

```
<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason why? Usually it's not a good idea to try to change Android design practice...

Comment: actually yes
i want to make the layout under the action bar looks like it's a part of the action bar

Comment: That's actually pretty cool, I would recommend you using Hierarchy Viewer and seeing what is the actual component that is. What I'm guessing is that it is a padding instead of a divider...

Comment: sorry for that what do you mean by Hierarchy Viewer??
is it like the outline and properties
i mean is it a tap or a class?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement a `Translucent Action Bar`:

[Custom Translucent Android ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749261/custom-translucent-android-actionbar)

[Show ImageView partly behind transparent ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381567/show-imageview-partly-behind-transparent-actionbar)

Define `themes`:

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and styles for your `Action Bar`:

```
<resources>
<style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionBar.Transparent">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then apply it in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: its worked
but for some reason the layout just under the action bar disappeared
while the other layouts and views are there
i will try to figure it out thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.whatever_theme_you_have">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The divider is contained for actionbar background image.

Try to change actionbar background image. Please refer to below codes.

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">{SET BACKGROUND FOR YOU}</item>
</style>
```