# Removing line or divider between action bar and main screen in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I remove line or divider between action bar and main screen?
How can I change the color of this divider in android?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to remove the divider under the action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950839/i-want-to-remove-the-divider-under-the-action-bar)

Comment: I saw that question before but I can't remove divider with those answers, can you explain, divider related to which style of action bar.and I of course explain that I don.t need overlay Action bar. I just remove that line such as you have style Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar in your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more effort I can find my ideal Theme.

1. First of all i must say that Theme.Holo.Light has a shadow in bottom of action bar if you want  to have not that shadow you must use Theme.Holo.
2. After you change the style you must change other settings for yourself like the code.

   ```
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
           <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
           <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
           <item name="android:colorBackground">#ff0000</item>
       </style>
       <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
           <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```
3. This below code is for my last challange that I found how to resolve it.

   ```
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
           <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
           <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
           <item name="android:colorBackground">#ff0000</item>
       </style>
       <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
           <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```
4. Below Image is for first Code, If you notice there isn't any divider.

[image]

1. And below Image is for second Code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for  android:Theme.Holo :)

Answer (score 13):

Simply insert the attribute windowContentOverlay to your theme. It's way too simple this way.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This removes only the shadow, not the line

Answer (score 3):

None of these solutions worked for me. I ended up adding this code to the `onCreate()` event of my `MainActivity`:

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setElevation(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

On Kotlin, you can use `supportActionBar?.elevation = 0f` to remove the shadow of the **ActionBar**.

Add this code to the `onCreate()` function of the desired activity. For example:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Hide ActionBar shadow
        supportActionBar?.elevation = 0f
    }
```

The `?.` operator controls *Null Pointer Exception* if you have no **ActionBar** on this Activity.

**Note:** If you are **not** using *AppCompat*, call `actionBar?.elevation = 0f` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

I just added the following line of code to the onCreate() method

```
 getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use AppCompat you need set **parent="Theme.AppCompat"**, not **"Theme.AppCompat.Light"** (the same stands for ActionBar) :)

For example: 
    
        @style/MyActionBar
        true
        
        @style/MyActionBar
        true

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!--For compatibility-->
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml file , look for your AppTheme style and add the following style into it

```
        <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

what it actually does is that it sets the background of the divider between activity window and action bar as transparent.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `AppBarLayout` nothing of that will help. I found the solution using :

```
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
        appBarLayout.setOutlineProvider(null);
```