# How can I remove the line between the action bar and the main screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to remove this line between the action bar and the main screen:

[image]

This is my AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/azulBewa</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/azulBewa</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_up_button_zeplin</item>
</style>
```

And this is the XML for my toolbar

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/azulBewa"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"


        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"

        />
```

I've tried several things ([click here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584078/removing-line-or-divider-between-action-bar-and-main-screen-in-android) but they didn't work properly.

Comment: can you post you xml file

Comment: @PramodWaghmare which one?

Comment: @mt0s No, I hadn't  removed it but I've just done it and it is working!! Thanks so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mt0s I figured out what I was doing wrong. In my case, it was the "elevation" tag, so I removed it.