# Transparent Actiobar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to give transparent effect to my action bar. I have used the following line to make it work that way, but strangely on my Nexus 5 I am can see the bar coming, but on my galaxy nexus I don't see it at all.

I am not sure why this is coming up on N5? How to solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);
```

Here is the screenshot for both Galaxy nexus running Jelly Bean (4.3) and Nexus 5 running kitkat (4.4.4)

**Galaxy Nexus:** showing transparent action bar perfectly:

[image]

**Nexus 5:** showing transparent action bar: (A horizontal line is shown)

[image]

**Update 2:**

I managed to remove the line on N5 by using the following style

```
  styles.xml in Values-v14 folder

  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"></style>

  then added theme to specific activity in manifext:

      <activity
        android:name=".Profile"
        android:label="@string/profile"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

but then all my text, dialog format have changed in this activity. It has become dark. It doesn't change even though I programatically change the theme for dialog. I am not sure what is wrong? Can someone help me out with this?

**Update 1:** As per @erakitn advice: I tried the following with few changes:

```
<!-- Transparent ActionBar Style -->
<style name="CustomThemeTransparent" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<!-- Activity Theme with transparent ActionBar -->
<style name="CustomThemeTransparentLight" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomThemeTransparent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomThemeTransparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I have getting the following error:

```
1. error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
2. error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
3. error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBarOverlay'.
```

Comment: have you try with transparent image as background?

Comment: i got your problem.

you need to remove divider from [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950839/i-want-to-remove-the-divider-under-the-action-bar

Comment: @Imtiyaz: I already that link. That would be a solution for setting background image manually. That is not the case for me. i am setting the background dynamically.

Comment: @TheDevMan can you post a picture what the dialog looks like

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: Check this link: http://postimg.org/image/cqws7xf0n/ and http://postimg.org/image/ijrb2wbhj/ - It used be white now it has become dark with text color getting change accordingly - Thanks!

Comment: @TheDevMan post the creation of dialog and the minimum API of your application

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin : Check this link which shows the dialog line:http://txs.io/9bqb Also my minimum API is 14

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove ActionBar shadow try to add `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` attribute to your Activity theme. Below there is an example of theme with transparent ActionBar. Define it in `res/styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Your App Theme-->
<style name="YourAppTheme.Light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <...>
</style>

<!-- Transparent ActionBar Style -->
<style name="YourAppTheme.Light.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<!-- Activity Theme with transparent ActionBar -->
<style name="YourAppTheme.TransparentActionBar.Light" parent="@style/YourAppTheme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YourAppTheme.Light.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YourAppTheme.Light.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And set this theme to your Activity:

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.name.YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/YourAppTheme.TransparentActionBar.Light" />
```

**UPD:**

If you are not using AppCompat or ABS you should use HOLO theme as parent for your theme. It seems you use light theme with dark ActionBar. Please try following solution:

```
<!-- Your App Theme-->
<style name="YourAppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <...>
</style>

<!-- Transparent ActionBar Style -->
<style name="YourAppTheme.Light.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<!-- Activity Theme with transparent ActionBar -->
<style name="YourAppTheme.TransparentActionBar.Light" parent="@style/YourAppTheme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YourAppTheme.Light.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @ erakitin : I tried your code but I am getting a couple of errors: "error:Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'." or "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBarOverlay'." also "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'." - Please note: I am not using sherlock or AppCompat Theme. Please check my question for updated line of code that I am trying out. Thanks!

Comment: I managed to get the transparent working, but then my dialog, text format all have changed. This does not get changed even though I programmatically change it? Any idea how to fix this part?

Comment: @TheDevMan please see my updated answer. If this solution is not helpful to you post please your base app theme. And I will update my answer once again.

Comment: The only thing @TheDevMan needed was `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`.

Comment: @PaulBurke yes, you are right! But I have no idea how to set it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

**Please don't change anything**

Your original code is just fine. All you need to do is set/apply the following attribute:

```
android:windowContentOverlay = true
```

Again, don't change your theme/style. Define a new one like this:

```
<style name="ConOver" >    <<== no parent
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Add this above your code:

```
// Add this line
// Lets you add new attribute values into the current theme
getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.ConOver, true);

// Rest stays the same
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new 
                              ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new 
                              ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
setContentView(R.layout.profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `DarkActionBar` as a theme now the dialog will turn black all around because that is the style `DarkActionBar` is using.

You can style your dialog from default light theme of **HOLO** for `dialogs`.

**sample:**

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
```

**EDIT:**

Change this:

`<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"></style>`

To

`<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>`

Comment: I tried it... but still the same. Changed it to <style name="dialogtheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">  </style>