# Android Activity with transparent background and Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

im trying to build a Popup for my Android App. It should be a Activity which doesn't use the whole screen, just 200dp on the right side of the screen and the rest should be transparent black.

A Picture of what it looks like / what i want to have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6APy6.png

**Java:**

```
public class ActivitySettings extends BaseActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Klicked " + motionEvent.getAction());
        // If we've received a touch notification that the user has touched
        // outside the app, finish the activity.
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == motionEvent.getAction()) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.cleverlize.substore.test.ActivitySettings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
    </activity>
```

**Style XML:**

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/itemPremium</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

So i just need the adjustment and the ActionBar... please Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Android manifest `file-> search for the required activity->` include this:

```
<--android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"-->
```

in the activity tag like this:

```
<activity
           android:name=".Services"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_services"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
</activity>
```

Comment: you have to use: this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); in activity after setting theme given above

Answer (score 2):

You can have acitivity without titlebar and actionbar in manifest with the theme as

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.demo.YourActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

and for layout

1. for transperancy  your base layout background will be `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`
2. your container layout will be 
   design as per your requirement with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Comment: but i still want to have the action bar, so NoTitleBar doesn't work for me.

Comment: please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455314/how-to-make-the-actionbar-transparent

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Activity layout is inside the LinearLayout, set the inner layout margin from left 200sp:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200sp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text Display"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```