# Transparent ActionBar is not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, transparency

I'm not able to set the transparency or any other color to the Actionbar. My style.xml:

```
<style name="thin_actionbar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/thin_actionbar_style</item>

</style>
<style name="thin_actionbar_style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/translucent_control</item>
</style>
```

tranlucent_color: like the bar in the screenshot below.
Looks like this. It's just grey:

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: can you post `R.color.translucent_control` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
<item name="android:background">@null</item>
```

If this does'nt  helps you, Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726214/transparent-actionbar-custom-tabcolor) link with this Code

Call `setStackedBackgroundDrawable()` on your `ActionBar`

`getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));`

**OR** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381567/show-imageview-partly-behind-transparent-actionbar) link , this code

`<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    ...
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item> <!-- for ActionBarSherlock -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>`

For making ActionBar Transparent.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I think the `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` did it. But now I can see the Navigation Drawer underneath the Actionbar. Is there a way to remove the part of the Drawer under the bar?

Answer (score 0):

for back ground you can use :

```
 <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

i hope it will help