# Add Activity's background image in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application, I want to override the color of `ActionBar` and make it translucent. *(color hex #40000000)*

I'm also using a background image in my Activity.

Issue is the ActionBar not taking the background image as its part. That is the image is starting below the action bar. *(as you can see in the screenshot below)*

It seems the bacground color of ActionBar is white and the translucent color is rendered over it.

Another issue is, I'm also displaying a view just below to action bar. (See image below)

The height of this view is same as the height of Action bar. Fo this I'm using below code in my `onCreate()`

```
private void setTopPanelHeight() {
    // Calculating ActionBar height
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        // Height in pixels.
        Integer actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        // Changing panel height.
        View panelView = findViewById(R.id.view_panel_below_action_bar);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) panelView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (int) actionBarHeight;
        panelView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

<<

As suggested in many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381748) & in [android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html), I tried to use:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

And then increased my layout top-margin as suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html#TopMargin)

```
`android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`
```

But, no use.

How can I make my background image included in the ActionBar & also do not disturb my view_below_actionbar & `navigation drawer`.

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windowActionBarOverlay` should work.

If your using android support library, then you need to do like this

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

Here is an example custom style ...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#40000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this `library` -> [GlassActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/GlassActionBar)

You can download an example of the library from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manuelpeinado.glassactionbardemo)

It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this has worked.

This will overlay your main content of activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimaryTranslucent</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/colorPrimaryTranslucent</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/colorPrimaryTranslucent</item>
</style>
```

But if you want ActionBar translucent but don't overlay your content and your background image be under translucent ActionBar do as following.

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_image</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimaryTranslucent</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/colorPrimaryTranslucent</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/colorPrimaryTranslucent</item>
</style>
```