# Show the ImageView behind the Appcompat ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am using theme as:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I want to show the ImageView partly behind the the ActionBar. I have tried [Show ImageView partly behind transparent ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381567/show-imageview-partly-behind-transparent-actionbar) and searched on google, but can't find the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) or [Support Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

With Toolbar, you can add it in your XML File just like any other View.

In your Activitys onCreate call setActionBar(toolbar) / setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Or try to add these two lines in your style:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

But using the Toolbar is actually pretty simple and the new standard.

Read this to get started: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: Hey I have edited the code which I am using, but the ActionBar doesn't become translucent as I was thinking of using the second approach, Is something wrong the way i am using Appcompat... Also can you provide the code describing how to use toolbar to make actionbar translucent..

Comment: Use a ColorDrawable, set its alpha to 0 and set it as the ActionBars background. ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(); cd.setAlpha(0); actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(cd); With ToolBar it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked but it makes transparent action bar whether I use 128 or 255 or 0 in setAlpha function, I want translucent action bar...

Comment: I added:  ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.picture); cd.setAlpha(128); getSuportActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(cd); then worked... BTW thanks a lot

Comment: ColorDrawable takes a color as argument, nor a resource ID. Like getResources().getColor(R.color.someColor); Glad it works ;)